# ASP.net MVC - specify full path of a Display Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, display-templates

Is it possible to specify the full path of a Display or Editor template?

For example, I have the following model:

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public class ChildModel { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `ParentController` and a `ChildController` and I would like to put the Child display template view in the Views/Child/DisplayTemplates/ChildModel.cshtml and the ParentModel.cshtml view in Views/Parent/DisplayTemplates/ParentModel.cshtml.

Right now it can't find the Child display template because it is looking in Views/Shared and Views/Parent.

Is it possible to specify the full path of a Display Template or write an HtmlHelper that can specify the folder(s) to look in?

Comment: There is a solution to this however it will mean a performance hit on your application. Is that a trade off you are willing to take?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is.  This is precisely the reason Views/Shared exists.  Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: It depends on how big of a performance hit it is. I suppose I could always try it and see if it is noticeable and take it from there.

Comment: @MystereMan In reality? I basically have one "main" controller that returns normal views and a bunch of AJAX dialogs that communicate with all of the other controllers. Lets say I have 10 "child" controllers and each one has an Edit and a Create ajax dialog. These ALL need to go into Views/Shared now. I would just like to be able to organize things a little better. I would be happy if I could store them in Views/Shared/Child as well, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out a way that works with only one slight drawback:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Child, "Child/ChildModel")
```

I created the following folder:

`Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Child` and placed `ChildModel.cshtml` in the folder. The drawback to this is that it no longer uses the model name to determine the template name and I imagine it is probably ignoring `UIHint` as well, but it does allow me to organize my Shared display templates a little better.